# How to repeat a step in Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am passing `List<Merchantdetails>` to MongoDb query. For each MerchantDetails there are more than 1 million records in MongoDb. So I am using skip and limit of Spring data MongoDb. So I fetch, 100,000 records in One query execution for one Merchant.

Next I want to read these 100,000 records in TransactionItemReader and process it to ItemProcssor and then these records should be passed to ItemWriter. Once these 100,000 records are written. Next 100,000 records should be fetched from MongoDb for same merchant. Similaröy it should be read by reader, processed by processor and then written by writer. Then in next iteration, similar thing should happen for next Merchant.

To avoid the OutOfMemoryError by loading all the Transaction Record in one go, I am using this.

I am thinking to execute the step repeatedly. For example, In first execution of Step, 100,000 records fetched, fed to reader, processor processed it and then writer wrote it. Then again this step need to be executed with some skip count maintained in some context which should be used to skip already fetched records and next 100,000 records should fetched and processed and written.

How can I achieve this requirement? I am new to Spring batch.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Pagination for that purpose.
You can include this while overriding the `read()` method of `ItemReader` class.

**Sample Code**

```
Pageable pageRequest = new PageRequest(offSet, limit);
mongoRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
++offSet;
```

Comment: This is available out-of-the-box using MongoItemReader

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci I am passing selection criteria in the query, so using MongoTemplate which doesn't have any implementation for find method which can take Pageable as argument. Is there any other way to achieve this without using MongoRepository or if I can pass my selection criteria to findAll() through query ?

Comment: I have achieved it using step repeat. Another issue, I am facing is , I want to write header multiple times(one header for each merchant for group of transaction) in same file, when I am using FlatFileHeaderCallback, Header is written first time only when ItemWriter gets called first time, for the next time step is repeating, header is not getting written again to same file for next merchant's transaction. Any help, how can I achieve it ?